# Compare custom field values

Tags: plugins

I have created a page that receives information and filters the posts by that choice. The page gets the information with _GET and I use the following code to send the query

```
$postss = new WP_Query([
                'post_type'      => 'post',
                'meta_query' => 
                array( 
                    array(
                        'key' => 'City:',
                        'value' => $city,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        array('key' => 'Time:',
                        'value' => 'hour',
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                        ),
                        array('key' => 'Time:',
                        'value' => 'min',
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'cat' => $category,
                'posts_per_page' => 9,
                'post_status'    => 'publish',
                'paged'          => $paged
            ]);
```

However my issue is, I have an input where the user can specify the city, then the category and then the time. The city and category work fine, but when we come to time I have placed few options with a drop down : under 1 hour, under 2 hours, under 3 hours etc . With this I can easily check with php if the time value is 1 2 3 etc and simply create the query

```
where time LIKE '%hour%'
```

however when the user chooses the 1, means that it's not just 1 hour, but it can also include minutes, so for example 30 minutes, so the results shold include 1 hour, but all minutes, so the query should be something like

```
where time like '%min%' OR time like '%hour%'
```

Also there is an issue, I don't know how exactly to add the % symbol (because sometimes there is 10 min sometimes it's 20 minutes - plural) so

```
LIKE '%min%'
```

would be okay, but not the same for hous, since if i do

```
LIKE '%hour%'
```

it will also include hours (2 3, not just 1 hour), so it should be

```
where time like '%hour'
```

in sql is easy, but with the wp_query I am not sure where to place the % symbol.

ps:I read that when I use the LIKE with meta_query automatically adds the % symbols at fron and end of the string, is there a way to remove them and just add it at front or in back, but not both?

Example values in meta:
City:New York, Tokyo, London

Time:10 minutes, 5 minutes, 20 minutes, 1 hour, 1.5 hours, 2 hours, 3 hours

Comment: what are the values of your meta? These are highly unusual, e.g. I would expect a time to be stored as a standardised time type value that the database can understand, not a string of text such as "5 hours 3 min". You may also find a performance improvement by using a `city` taxonomy instead of using post meta.

Comment: Here are some example values:
Time could be: 50 minutes; 10 minutes, 1 hour; 1.5 hours; 2 hours;3 hours
And the point is if the user chooses - Under 1 hour we should show all that contains "min" and all that contain the word hour (meaning singular). When the user choses 2 hours for example we need to include again "min" the word "hour" but this time with % symbol, so it can be singular and plural.

Comment: the words "hour" and "minute" etc do not need to be stored in your post meta, they can be added to the UI in the frontend/WP Admin. By including them in your stored values you are making life much harder, and eliminating lot of possible solutions. For example there is a trivial solution that could be used by telling WP it's a date/time value and doing a comparison, but this is not an option for you as long as you used this bespoke method of storing the value. Do not store "5 hours 20 minutes", store "5:20:00", giving you access to all the date/time comparison/math/operators

Comment: I reversed the LIKE to NOT LIKE and seems to be working, if I say NOT LIKE 'hours' this shows anything that is singular of hour, and any minutes, however when the user selects 2 hours for example then the not like comparison will become something like - not like "min" not like "1 hour" etc. I guess your idea is better, I should just change the hours mins to the standard format, and then when I show them I should convert them. What would be the standard for the following examples: 20 mins; 1.5 hours; 5 hours; 
00:20:00, 01:30:00,05:00:00 ?

Comment: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, but even storing it as just the number of minutes e.g. `60` would let you use the math comparators such as `BETWEEN` or `>`. You can use WP functions such as `human_time_diff` or `human_readable_duration` to display it as human readable text, and it'll even localise it. Your current solution is unintelligable in say german or japanese

Comment: Okay I will edit the hours/minutes and will add them in HH:MM:SS, any examples how to then do the query to properly compare for my example?

Comment: I tried with human_readable_duration seems to be working fine, but it displays too much information. For example if I have 05:00:00 it displays 5 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds, can I change this to something shorter?

Comment: are the hours times of the day, or durations

Comment: Currently I changed the values to HH:MM:SS but with wordpress function human readable duration it changes it too way too much information. This would be better: 05:00:00 -> 5 hours; 05:30:00 -> 5.5 hours or 5 hours 30 mins, basically excluse empty values etc. I guess I could create my own function to check and exclude the 0, just wondering for your opintion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing your values as "5 hours 13 minutes" instead store them as timestamps, e.g. `5:13` for 5h 13m

This way you can use the date/time comparator operations to answer questions

E.g. to get items under 5 hours and 30 minutes:

```php
$args = [
    ...
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'meta_key'     => 'time',
            'meta_value'   => date( "5:30" ),
            'meta_compare' => '<',
            'type'         => 'TIME',
        ],
    ],
];
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This will match a 3 hour post, or a 4:20 post, or a 5h 29min post.

You may need to add `:00` for the seconds on to the end of all code and values.

For display you can use `human_readable_duration`. This will include the seconds though, but the function is very simple so copying and modifying it to your requirements should be straight forward.

Comment: Will this work if I have changed the values to HH:MM:SS ?

Comment: it should yes, `12:30:00`, I've a modification to make to the code example to tell WP it's a time value

Comment: The function is helpful, but doesn't allow me to hide unnecessary info, for example if seconds are 00, it still shows them, the functin itself is about 20 lines of code, seems unnecessary to copy it inside my code. I guess I can just go with explode : and then remove any double digits 00 and etc?

Comment: it'll be less than 20 lines if you modify it and give it your own name, it has the advantage that it will catch bad values such as `99:09:99` and that it localises the response.

Comment: I used your example with modifications for the comparison, for instance instead of just < I added = so if user choses less than 5 hours it will include anything under 5 hours and also 5 hours. Also had to add minutes and seconds to the variable, when the user choses under 1 hour tha value is "1" so I add 00:00 after it, for proper comparison. Now I will try to modify the functionality that displays the time in readable format.

Comment: I used substr to trim the first char if it is zero, and also delete the last three chars, so that 05:30:00 becomes 5:30, also 00:30:00 becomes 0:30.

Comment: One more question, how would be the proper way to order by time either asc or desc?